# React native slide navigation approach?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, navigation

I am not asking direct code.Just want to know different approaches.

I am new to react native. I am trying to create a button which I can slide/swipe and it will trigger screen change.(navigation)

Answer (score 1):

`<ScrollView>` can be used to swipe between different pages, see [this](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.45/docs/using-a-scrollview.html) for more detail.

For navigation in general, I think a better option would be to use the react-navigation library as it offers a wide array of options, which can be nested together to achieve a better effect for the end-user. See [this link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html) for the same.

Comment: thanx for answering but I want to scroll in a horizontal way, and want to scroll the button not the whole screen

Comment: @vish_youtube
You can do this by adding the button you want to scroll within a `<ScrollView>` tag. If you want additional padding, you can add a stylesheet to specify the area to be allowed to scroll.
Also, `<ScrollView>` can be used for horizontal scrolling too.